# How to eliminate $\dot{x}$ term in differential equation $\ddot{x} + p(t) \dot{x} + q(t) x = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Vladimir Arnold's *Ordinary Differential Equations* (page 252) states that "the more general equation $\ddot{x} + p(t) \dot{x} + q(t) x = 0$ is easily reduced to the form $\ddot{x} + q(t) x = 0$". The book doesn't explain *how* to do this; I guess it's assumed to be obvious, but it's not obvious to me.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: The procedure is easy to execute, but it's not obvious.

Comment: The book is wrong if they used same letter. They should have used different letters. clearly  $x''+p x'+q x=0$ can't just be rewritten as $x'' + q x=0$. There is no such magic in math. Now if you use different letters, this is something different.

Comment: @Nasser Good point. I did understand that $q$ in the second equation was a different function from $q$ in the first, but I think I didn't understand that a change of variables had been performed, such that $x$ was also a different variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $\ddot{x} + p(t) \dot{x} + q(t) x = 0$,

let

$u(t) = \exp\left({\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tp(k)dk}\right) \ x(t)$

$r(t)=q(t)-\frac{1}{2}p'(t)-\frac{1}{4}p^2(t)$

Then it is straightforward to check that $u''+r(t)u = 0$.

In case you're wondering how to come up with stuff like that, the easiest way to do this is to rewrite the equation in differential operator form and then simply factor out the quadratic expression in terms of differential operators.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1989856)

Comment: Thanks very much! Maybe include the main points of the answer here and then I can accept and upvote?

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thank you for pointing out. I'll edit the answer. Indeed, the links may become invalid, didn't think about that

Comment: For OP: you don't need to guess the integrating factor either. You can let $x(t) = a(t) u(t)$ and determine what $a$ needs to be to cancel the middle term. If you write it out this way, you'll see why it's an integrating factor pretty quickly.